# joining two tables and overwriting one colum

Tags: sql

I am trying to join to tables as image attached shows,

table 1 will have exactly the same records as table 2 except one field with is not equal

I would like to merge them so i will have the extended table :

1. have all records from table2, if we ignore isempty field, table 1 is always in table2
2. when table1.isEmpty=1 , the merged result will have isempty=1, and that record will be overwritten

check attached images for more details

[image]

[image]

[image]

the table 3 as shown, will have all the records from table 2 but overwritten when necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, A.DESC, CASE B.ISEMPTY
                WHEN 1 THEN 1
                ELSE A.ISEMPTY
                END CASE AS ISEMPTY 
FROM TABLE2 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 B ON A.ID=B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Having trouble understanding your data. Do you want something like this?

```
select table1.id, table1.name, (table1.isEmpty or table2.isEmpty) as isEmpty
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```